# Close children of child form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have main form which is MDI parent.

Inside I opened second (same solution, different project) form like this:

```
Dim f As New mynevproj.frm_list
With f
  .MdiParent = Me
  .Show()
End With
```

In those new form (frm_list) I open another new form in few instances:

```
Dim fa As New frm_art1
With fa
  .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
  .Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + 20 + (inst * 20), Me.Location.Y))
   AddHandler .aClosed, AddressOf frm_artikl_Closed
  .Show()
End With
```

What happens?

When I open few instances of frm_art1 and then closes frm_list I expect that all frm_art1 will be closed in order to closing frm_list.

But that doesn't happen.

Every time I click (X) to close frm_list one instance of frm_art1 closes and finally when all frm_art1 was closed then frm_frm_list closes.

How to get that all forms opened through frm_list closes when I close frm_list.

This works good in non MDI enviroinment.

Now I try additionally this in form_closing of frm_list:

```
For Each frm As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
  If frm.Name = "frm_art1" Then
    frm.Close()
  End If
Next
```

And this also doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the frm_list the owner of the other forms:

```
Dim fa As New frm_art1
With fa
  .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
  .Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + 20 + (inst * 20), Me.Location.Y))
  AddHandler .aClosed, AddressOf frm_artikl_Closed
  .Owner = Me
  .Show()
End With
```

Comment: In that case (.Show(Me)) frm_list closes immediatelly but all frm_art1 remains open (minimized in taskbar).

Comment: @user1697111 Hmm, yes, MDI can be goofy.  Updated answer.  Set the `Owner` property to the calling form instead.

Comment: Still goofy, Lars :( Now frm_list closes immediatelly and all frm_art1 remains "normal" (not minimized). Further ideas to try?

Comment: @user1697111 I'm not getting that.  When I close the MDI Child Form that opened the other forms, they all close.

Comment: My child form is in other project (same solution), that can be maybe important? Now I see that with "Owner = Me" variant I can close wanted forms on closing frm_list through foreach loop! Well, acceptable, that mean - solved. Thank you very much Lars!

Comment: @user1697111 For posts that solver your question, feel free to tick the check mark next to that post. It will mark it as answered.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks. I would like to vote too for your ansewer but still havent minimum of 15 points. Sorry.